# Android custom view

Tags: android, view, radio-button

I need some view that works like **toggle button**, but with my layout. For example i have `ImageView` and two `TextViews` below. I want to change background color, text color and image in all states of toggle button(on, off). I searched a lot. I can change image or add some style to it, but i need to use my layout instead of their. Is there any good solution? Or the only way is to extend ToggleButton class and override onDraw method? Custom view sample in ON and OFF states [dl.dropbox.com/u/1927199/test.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1927199/test.png)

Comment: In ON and OFF states i want the same LinearLayout with ImageView and two TextViews. When the state changed i want to change image, text color and layout background

Comment: can you post sample screen shot for both ON and OFF states of your custom toggle button.

Comment: Do you want to create a custom view or same toggle button functionality in an activity ?

Comment: I need the view with the same behavior that has toggle button but i want it look like dl.dropbox.com/u/1927199/test.png

Answer (score 0):

No need to override the onDraw for this requirement.

You get the TextView by findViewById(R.id....) and can change its textcolor.

If yu want to chane the background color of the activity, get the main Layout (root) using findViewById and can change its setBackground(Color.blue) or any drawable.

Same can be doen with Image view too.

After doing all these 3, just call

```
root.invalidate();
```

This will refresh all the components.

Comment: I no need to change something in layout of some activity. I need the view with the same behavior that has toggle button but i want it look like dl.dropbox.com/u/1927199/test.png

Comment: @user1187667, add/upload the image in your Question. Can't upload it in a comment.